# VB.Net Dispose/Garbage Collector not releasing resources?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

using VS 2015 here...just made a small testing program to compare the performance difference between an async webrequest using tasks and the way I was doing it before with HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse

But the point is I tried to dispose of the state object I was using for the async requests by implementing IDispoable, but in my diagnostics it shows that the allocated RAM size remains the same?  I was under the impression that calling dispose would release the resources the object was using?  Here is the code I am using, I also tried just setting the object to Nothing.

```
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1
    Private sw As New Stopwatch

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim req As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://example.com")
        Dim state As New RequestState
        state.req = req
        req.BeginGetResponse(AddressOf respCallback, state)
    End Sub

    Private Sub respCallback(ar As IAsyncResult)
        Dim state As RequestState = ar.AsyncState
        state.resp = state.req.EndGetResponse(ar)
        state.respStream = state.resp.GetResponseStream
        state.respStream.BeginRead(state.buffer, 0, 1024, AddressOf readCallback, state)
    End Sub

    Private Sub readCallback(ar As IAsyncResult)
        Dim state As RequestState = ar.AsyncState
        Dim read As Integer = state.respStream.EndRead(ar)
        If read > 0 Then
            state.respBody += System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, read)
            state.respStream.BeginRead(state.buffer, 0, 1024, AddressOf readCallback, state)
        Else
            state.respStream.Close()
            MsgBox(state.respBody)
            state.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub

Public Class RequestState
    Implements IDisposable

    Public req As HttpWebRequest
    Public resp As HttpWebResponse
    Public respStream As IO.Stream
    Public buffer(1024) As Byte
    Public respBody As String

#Region "IDisposable Support"
Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If Not disposedValue Then
        If disposing Then
            ' TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
            req = Nothing
            resp.Close()
            resp.Dispose()
            resp = Nothing
            respStream.Close()
            respStream.Dispose()
            respStream = Nothing
            buffer = Nothing
            respBody = Nothing
        End If

        ' TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override Finalize() below.
        ' TODO: set large fields to null.
    End If
    disposedValue = True
End Sub

    ' TODO: override Finalize() only if Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    'Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    '    ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above.
    '    Dispose(False)
    '    MyBase.Finalize()
    'End Sub

    ' This code added by Visual Basic to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above.
        Dispose(True)
        ' TODO: uncomment the following line if Finalize() is overridden above.
        ' GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
#End Region
End Class
```

Comment: Run CA on your app and it will do a decent job of pointing out things like that you dont actually dispose of that `respStream `

Comment: (re to deleted comment) There is no code in `Sub Dispose(boolean)` to dispose of anything.  Also, RAM is not the same as resources.  You can sometimes see handles and such leak away in Task Manager by showing the USER and GDI objects columns.

Comment: I don't know much about asynchronous programming, but I believe there are some objects to dispose there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply implementing `IDisposable` doesn't *automatically* free up memory, all that is up to the programmer to release managed and unmanaged resources.

In the `Dispose(disposing As Boolean)` method you would have to call `Close()` or `Dispose()` on each of your variables that implement the disposing functionality:

```
Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If Not disposedValue Then
        If disposing Then
            'Here you dispose all managed resources.
            respStream.Close()
            respStream.Dispose()
            resp.Close()
        End If
    End If
    disposedValue = True
End Sub
```

When you are done with your asynchronous actions, be sure to close the `IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle` object. You should be able to do this in the end of every callback method:

```
ar.Close()
```

Comment: Hi, I set the RequestState objects fields to Nothing and called Dispose on the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse fields in the implementation of IDisposable's Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean) method, and still I see to not be freeing the resources. I'm probably doing something wrong :P

Comment: I updated my question with the new implementation of Dispose.  When I start the app, the baseline RAM Usage is 20mb, when I click Button 1 and the request is sent, it goes up to 22mb, and never back down to baseline despite my attempts at releasing that 2mb.

Comment: @DavidStampher : Perhaps the garbage collector hasn't run yet? It's purpose is to collect any unreferenced (or disposed) objects. It doesn't run instantly, you know.

Comment: Yeah, I've had it running roughly 5 mins and still not having the resources unallocated.

Comment: @DavidStampher : And what if you force it to run several times? Some memory should be released. Also try running it synchronously, to see if some async objects are the thieves.

Comment: I just added the code in Button 1's click event into a For Loop, memory usage plateau'd and didn't go back to baseline, which is what I was hoping to accomplish.

Comment: @DavidStampher : I'd use a memory profiler to help you find the actual leak... Also, my latest update to my answer is as far as I can help you I'm afraid.

Comment: It isnt going to yield back every byte you allocate, such as that little buffer(1024).  However, if the app needs 2 more such objects, it may not have to ask the OS for more memory because it still has some handy over here.  How are you determining the leak? Just by something in task manager?

Comment: @Visual Vincent, in regards to your last edit, I added the call to Close() on the asyncwaithandles in the callbacks as you suggested, sadly it is still the same issue.  I'll figure this out eventually I'm sure, because it's going to keep bothering me haha.  Thanks for the help...i'll look for the memory profiler you suggested.

Comment: @Plutonix Using the Diagnostic Tools in VS2015.  Just a realtime graph of memory usage as the app runs.

Comment: When I set the iterations to a higher number, like sending 1000 async requests, I am seeing the results I expected it seems.  I guess I just needed to scale up more to see the effect?  I'll mark Vincents response as the answer because that is probably part of why I am seeing it work when having more than just a few objects in allocated memory.

Comment: @DavidStampher : I'd say what [**Plutonix said in his comment**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405622/vb-net-dispose-garbage-collector-not-releasing-resources/38405729?noredirect=1#comment64220357_38405729) also plays its part here.